# Postfix daemon connects and immediately disconnects periodically

Tags: postfix, monit, smtpd

Postfix's smtpd(daemon used to receive mail) flaps/(connects/disconnects) every 30 seconds with the connection from localhost.

```
May 24 17:33:03 ---- postfix/smtpd[8397]: connect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
May 24 17:33:03 ---- postfix/smtpd[8397]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1] ...
...
...
May 24 17:33:34 ---- postfix/smtpd[8397]: connect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
May 24 17:33:34 ---- postfix/smtpd[8397]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1] ...
```

Postfix seems to be working correctly and I am not seeing any faults.

Answer (score 1):

Monit connects to check if Postfix (amongst other applications) to see if it is alive. Resulting in the connect and disconnect in the log.

Stop monitoring Postfix with Monit to verify.